# MySQL-Update-Function Inserts New Row

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a page updating database-entries. Should work, but it doesn't. Instead of updating data it creates a new entry.

**Explanation**: usually the code should let me update the existing entry. That's why I use WHERE c.id='$ceid'. But even though I am updating the entry with ID 15 I then have a new entry with the ID 16.

```
UPDATE customer AS c SET c.company='$company', 
                                        c.contractnumber='$contractnumber',
                                        c.delivery='$delivery',
                                        c.quit='$quit',
                                        c.unsubscription='$quitdate',
                                        c.alert='$alert' 
                    WHERE c.id='$ceid'
```

So the MySQL-query is right so far as it seems.

So the problem must be somewhere else, before or after the query. Most likely it happens before the query as I used to outcomment the if(!emtpy...)-part. But what is it?

```
    <html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
<?
    $link = mysqli_connect("server", "user", "pw", "db");
?>
<body>

<h1>Kundenansicht</h1>
<p>Kundennummer <?php echo $_GET["id"]; ?></p>
<p><?php echo $_GET["name"]; echo " "; echo $_GET["surname"]; ?></p>
<p>Vertrag <?php echo $_GET["cid"]; ?></p>
<?

$uid = $_GET["id"];
echo $uid;
echo "<br>";
$name = $_GET["name"];
$surname = $_GET["surname"];
$cid = $_GET["cid"];
echo "CID: ";
echo $cid;
echo "<br>";
        if ($link->connect_error) {
             die("Connection failed: " . $link->connect_error);
        } 
        mysqli_set_charset($link,"utf8");

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM customer WHERE id ='".$cid."' AND custnumber = '".$uid."'";
        $result = mysqli_query($link,$sql) or die (mysqli_error());
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);






?>


      <div id="AddContract" class="w3-container">
        <form action="customerview.php?id=<? echo $uid ?>&name=<? echo $name ?>&surname=<? echo $surname ?>"  method="post">
            <label>ID</label> <!-- e.g. PluSStrom-->
            <input class="w3-input w3-border" type="number" name="id" id="id" value="<? echo $row["id"]; ?>">
            <label>Anbieter</label> <!-- e.g. PluSStrom-->
            <input class="w3-input w3-border" type="text" name="company" id="company" value="<? echo $row["company"]; ?>">
            <label>Vertragsnummer</label> <!-- Vertragsnummer-->
            <input class="w3-input w3-border" type="number" name="contractnumber" id="contractnumber" value="<? echo $row["contractnumber"]; ?>">   
            <label>Lieferdatum</label> <!-- Kündigungsfrist in Wochen-->
            <input class="w3-input w3-border" type="date" name="deliverydate" id="deliverydate" value="<? echo $row["delivery"]; ?>">                   
            <label>Kündigungsfrist (Wochen)</label> <!-- Kündigungsfrist in Wochen-->
            <input class="w3-input w3-border" type="number" name="quit" id="quit" value="<? echo $row["quit"]; ?>">     
            <label>Kündigungsdatum</label>
            <input class="w3-input w3-border" type="date" name="qdate" id="qdate" value="<? echo $row["unsubscription"]; ?>">
            <input type="submit" class='w3-btn w3-black' name="submit" value="Eintragen">
        </form>
<?


// Check connection
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Escape user inputs for security
$ceid = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['id']);
$company = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['company']);
$contractnumber = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['contractnumber']);
$customernumber = $uid;
$quit = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['quit']);
$quitdate = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['qdate']);
$delivery = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['deliverydate']);
$qd = $quit * 7;

$alert = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, date('Y-m-d', strtotime($quitdate. " - $qd days")));

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

    if(!empty($customernumber) || !empty($contractnumber) ){
        $sql_upd = "UPDATE customer AS c SET c.company='$company', 
                                        c.contractnumber='$contractnumber',
                                        c.delivery='$delivery',
                                        c.quit='$quit',
                                        c.unsubscription='$quitdate',
                                        c.alert='$alert' 
                    WHERE c.id='$ceid'";



            if (mysqli_query($link, $sql_upd)) {
                echo "Record updated successfully";
            } else {
                echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($link);
            }



    } else {
        echo "ERROR: Nicht gespeichert. Kundennummer oder Vertragsnummer fehlen!";
    }



}
// close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Btw: I know working with get is not very safe. And the code isn't a beauty as I want to polish later, but struck with the problem above.

Comment: so, you are saying `UPDATE` creates new entry ? It is impossible.

Comment: I thought the same. And it happens. If you want, I can make a video.

Comment: can you point out, which query are you executing ?

Comment: Let me explain this way: on start I fill the form's inputs with the data from the select-query.
So I see which ID I am working on. Then I click on submit/Eintragen and here data will be used for the update-function with a where-condition so that I only update the entry with the same ID. But instead it creates a new entry with the changed data and a new ID.

Comment: just post the SQL, you have two SQL posted in your question, which one is causing issue ?

Comment: Also, remove all unnecessary code from your post.

Comment: what do you wanna do, insert or update?

Comment: The first code-segment is the one which I use to update. And, to answer user1506104's question, I want to update.
I don't like to remove the code as it seems that the UPDATE-code works, so problem might come from elsewhere in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have solved the problem. First, Ravi was right. Update can't create new entries. And insert did. Because I wanted to move to another page after submitting the form I abused action. Instead of using the update-code on the current page it went to the page referred to in action and added the data through the insert-code on this page.